# PL/SQL Trigger to calculate total attendance

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a trigger to calculate total attendance for each distinct record from the given table.

*DAILY_ATT*

[image]

The second table should generate output like this:

*TOTAL_ATT*

[image]

Here's what I have done:

```
CREATE TABLE daily_att 
  ( 
     roll_no    NUMBER(5), 
     subject    VARCHAR2(10), 
     attendance NUMBER(5), 
     date_att   DATE 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE total_att 
  ( 
     roll_no          NUMBER(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     total_attendance NUMBER(5) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO DAILY_ATT VALUES(1, 'MATHS', 0, '04-MAY-18');

INSERT INTO DAILY_ATT VALUES(1, 'ENG', 1, '04-MAY-18');

INSERT INTO DAILY_ATT VALUES(2, 'MATHS', 1, '04-MAY-18');

INSERT INTO DAILY_ATT VALUES(2, 'ENG', 1, '04-MAY-18');

INSERT INTO DAILY_ATT VALUES(1, 'MATHS', 1, '05-MAY-18');

INSERT INTO DAILY_ATT VALUES(1, 'ENG', 1, '05-MAY-18');

INSERT INTO DAILY_ATT VALUES(2, 'MATHS', 0, '05-MAY-18');

INSERT INTO DAILY_ATT VALUES(2, 'ENG', 0, '05-MAY-18');

SELECT * FROM DAILY_ATT;

CREATE OR replace TRIGGER att 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON daily_att 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SELECT SUM(attendance) 
    INTO   Total_att(total_attendance) 
    FROM   daily_att 
    WHERE  roll_no = :NEW.roll_no; 
END;
```

Comment: Please, add your code, table definitions, errors, **as text**, not as images. ALso, what is your question?

Comment: The value of TOTAL_ATTENDANCE in the table TOTAL_ATT should be displayed as the sum of ATTENDANCE from the table DAILY_ATTENDANCE for each distinct record.

Comment: Is this intentional, that you are using different table names in the script, than in the question?

Comment: Corrected it. The table names are DAILY_ATT & TOTAL_ATT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will serve your purpose**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_subtotal
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON DAILY_ATTENDANCE
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

V_ROLL_NO NUMBER(8); 
V_TOT_ATTENDANCE NUMBER(4);  

BEGIN
  SELECT ROLL_NO,SUM(ATTENDANCE) 
    INTO V_ROLL_NO,V_TOT_ATTENDANCE  
    FROM DAILY_ATTENDANCE
   WHERE ROLL_NO = :new.ROLL_NO AND DATE_ATT=TRUNC(SYSDATE);

    BEGIN
      update TOTAL_ATTENDANCE 
      set TOTAL_ATTENDANCE= TOT_ATTENDANCE
      where ROLL_NO = V_ROLL_NO;

      if sql%rowcount = 0 then
        -- no rows were updated, so the record does not exist
        insert into TOTAL_ATTENDANCE (ROLL_NO,TOTAL_ATTENDANCE )
        values ( V_ROLL_NO,V_TOT_ATTENDANCE );
      END IF;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wasn't it supposed to be a total of all records, not just for the current `DATE_ATT`? Or did I miss a requirement somewhere?

Comment: As this is `BEFORE` trigger, it will NOT have access to current data of `DAILY_ATTENDANCE`. If I remember correctly, how the mutating table problem works, you would not have this access even in an `AFTER` trigger fired `FOR EACH ROW`. As it also lacks triggering on `DELETE`, it will not reduce the totals, when daily records are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to not **abuse** a `Trigger` for this purpose. Simply create a view.

```
CREATE
    OR replace VIEW total_att AS
SELECT roll_no
    ,SUM(attendance) as total_attendance
FROM daily_att
GROUP BY roll_no;

select * FROM total_attendance;

ROLL_NO TOTAL_ATTENDANCE
1       3
2       2
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use this set of 2 triggers:

The core one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_subtotal
  AFTER UPDATE OF roll_no, attendance OR INSERT OR DELETE ON daily_att
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_roll_no daily_att.roll_no%TYPE;
  v_before  daily_att.attendance%TYPE;
  v_after   daily_att.attendance%TYPE;
  v_diff    daily_att.attendance%TYPE;
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING AND (:NEW.roll_no <> :OLD.roll_no) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Altering ROLL_NO is not allowed!' );
  END IF;

  IF NOT INSERTING THEN
    v_before := :OLD.attendance;
    v_roll_no := :OLD.roll_no;
  ELSE
    v_before := 0;
    v_roll_no := :NEW.roll_no;
  END IF;

  IF NOT DELETING THEN
    v_after := :NEW.attendance;
  ELSE
    v_after := 0;
  END IF;

  v_diff := v_after - v_before;

  IF INSERTING OR (v_diff <> 0) THEN
    UPDATE total_att
       SET total_attendance = total_attendance + v_diff
     WHERE roll_no = v_roll_no;

    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
      INSERT INTO total_att (roll_no, total_attendance)
      VALUES (v_roll_no, v_diff);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

An auxiliary one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_subtotal
  AFTER DELETE ON daily_att
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM total_att
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM daily_att d
                      WHERE total_att.roll_no = d.roll_no);
END;
```

I've assumed that `ROLL_NO` is never `NULL`, nor should ever be changed, and that `ATTENDANCE` is also never `NULL`. I basically ignored the `SUBJECT` and `DATE_ATT` columns, as from the question, they do not seem to impact the goal.

The auxiliary trigger can be dropped, if you do not need to handle deletes from the `DAILY_ATT` table, or can stand zero entries in `TOTAL_ATT` table, for things removed from `DAILY_ATT` completely.

For better performance, the check for `ROLL_NO` change should be moved to a separate `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. The auxiliary trigger will usually benefit much from an index on `ROLL_NO` in the `DAILY_ATT` table.

[Here's an SQL Fiddle for this.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf7c2/1)